# Minifying static files (js & css) using django-pipeline results in empty files

Tags: django, django-pipeline, yuglify

I have gone through all of the related posts similar to the issue I have, but none of them seem to solve my problem therefore my question.

When I run `python manage.py collectstatic` django-pipeline generates minified css file which has no content. Can someone please advise how I can resolve this issue.
I don't see any errors in my terminal. Using django 1.5.

Here's my django-pipeline specific settings:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE     = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
PIPELINE_ENABLED        = True
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR  = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'
PIPELINE_YUGLIFY_BINARY = '/usr/bin/env yuglify'


PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'page_style': {                        
        'source_filenames': (                       
          'css/header.css',
          'css/content.css',
          'jqm/grid.css'
        ),
        'output_filename': 'assets/compressed/page_style.min.css', 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Ubuntu and does typing `node` on the console return any output?

I just solved this (or a similar?) problem myself when I realized that I used `apt-get` to install Node(js) which turned out to install it as `nodejs` and not `node` (which is something else, according to Ubuntu).

If you `which yuglify`, you can find the path and edit the bang-line at the top to have to correct path to `nodejs` (it is currently `#!/usr/bin/env node`, for instance).

**I changed mine to `#!/usr/bin/env nodejs` and it seemed to solve the problem.**

YMMV.

Comment: A more complete solution might be to "not install node via apt-get". That's fine, but I wanted to post this workaround *just in case*.